# Error Unknown pseudo-op:cfi _ start proc

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Hello Each time i try to compile and link the gfortran compiler returns the following messages[image: Compiler message]

What could be the possible cause of such a problem and what are the possible solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the versions of gcc and g++ not matching. Check if g++ --version is the same as
gcc --version. This can be solved by ensuring that the environment variables of g++ and gcc are of the same version.Remove older compilers from the environment variable path and leave the newest